# Rails test unit access denied rename

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new here. I search everywhere and I haven't found anything. I'm using rails on windows 10. I'm following the basic tutorial of a sample app. When I execute "rails test" command in the console I get the following errors. I checked the permissions of each file and directory and all have the permissions needed. Can someone help me ?

I'm using rails **6.0.2.2 version.**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Hope I'll get answer here.

**Solution :** I installed ubuntu on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Stop your rails server before executing your tests: the server is keeping cache files locked and the testing framework is trying to alter them.

I encountered the same issue (while following what's probably [the same tutorial you were following](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages)) on Rails 6.0.3.4 on Windows 10 and doing so solved it. (launching the server again before executing tests reproduced it again)

**Update:** I thought this was a complete solution, but it's more complex than that. Here's my experience:

- running `rails test` while `rails server` is running results in the error;
- running `rails test` when `rails server` is not running *sometimes* results in the error.

I haven't encountered this error on Linux so far, so my guess is that the implementation of Rails of Windows is unstable and sometimes gets stuck locking its own files.

You can check if you can reproduce the same behaviour, but I would report it as a bug.